# How can I change the development version of a module?

Tags: community-official-site

Originally, the [Link Allowed Hosts](https://www.drupal.org/project/link_allowed_hosts) module, which I'm a maintainer of (with "administer releases" permission), started with a default branch of `1.0.x`. This branch was released and appeared since then as development version `1.0.x-dev`.

This was wrong, the default branch needs to be `1.x`. So I created a `1.x` branch, set it as default on the project's GitLab page and also released it. Still the development version stayed `1.0.x-dev`.

I also can't enable this branch in the project's "Releases" page as the matching checkbox is disabled.

How can I fix this? Or where can I file this issue?

---

[image: Screenshot of the Link Allowed Hosts releases edit screen with the inactive checkbox]

---

[image: Screenshot of how 1.0.x-dev appears as development version on the Link Allowed Hosts module page]

Comment: Does that mean this docs page at the bottom is _wrong_? https://www.drupal.org/project/views_minimum/git-instructions

Comment: Whoops that was supposed to be generic link. But on a project page, it says "git checkout -b 1.0.x" but on this page, it says 1.x: https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/git/git-for-drupal-project-maintainers/release-naming-conventions

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to select that branch as supported, as the *Supported* checkbox for the *1.** series is disabled by code. That is done by [`project_release_project_edit_releases()`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/project/-/blob/7.x-2.x/release/includes/project_edit_releases.inc#L11) which contains the following code. (drupal.org is still running on Drupal 7.)

```php
// Check if the maintainer is allowed to mark the branch as supported.
if (($supportable_branch_pattern = variable_get('project_release_supportable_branch_pattern_' . $node->type, variable_get('project_release_supportable_branch_pattern'))) && !preg_match($supportable_branch_pattern, $branch)) {
  $form['branches'][$branch]['supported']['#disabled'] = TRUE;
  $form['branches'][$branch]['supported']['#value'] = 0;
  $form['branches'][$branch]['recommended']['#disabled'] = TRUE;
  $form['branches'][$branch]['recommended']['#value'] = 0;
}
```

That is probably done because the settings for *1.** would also be valid for *1.0.**; using settings for the *1.** and the *1.0.** series would cause "conflicts" between two different settings.

As for in which queue you could file an issue, that is the [*Project* issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/project?categories=All), the queue for the project that handles projects and their releases on drupal.org. Probably this is seen as *works as designed*, but the *Project* maintainers are the only ones who can change that code and decide for any change.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to have this resolved is to as in the #drupal-infrastructure channel in Slack.